# Extreme Programming Projects Failures

Tags: extreme-programming

I searched the web for examples of extreme programming failure but I couldn't find any.

I found success stories, but I want to learn about the "other side of the coin".

So my question is only about projects that fail using XP. Why do they fail? I just want to hear some opinions about XP failures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The highest profile one I know of is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysler_Comprehensive_Compensation_System

Comment: More information from the programmer perspective (some of the big players were active on c2 at the time) - http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ChryslerComprehensiveCompensation and in particular http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CthreeProjectTerminated

Answer (score 9):

Agile projects can't fail.

They are only bound by Time not scope. So if you run out of time you just deliver what you have.

## Eureka! Success!

[image]

[image]

Comment: So if a customer ask for a product and you say "yes we can do that" (because XP is all about communication) and then you just can't deliver what you promise in the time you promise. Isn't that a failure in communication (which is an important value in XP)? You are just saying agile is the silver bullet to make any project succeed? If everyone use an agile project they will succeed?

Comment: @canha there is some debate on if [cancellation is failure](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IsEarlierCancellationFailure) or if an early termination of a project (that would be terminated anyways later with other methods) is success.